# Which ratio to choose to distribute values

Tags: ratio

I have simple problem. I want to calculate stock value of purchase products. So I am confuse about which part should I use to calculate ratio. Is it base price or total price (Price x qty).

With base price ration is 80 : 20 and for total its 88.88 : 11.12.
Which ever ratio is chosen the grand total will 1400 but stock values are different.

With base price item1 stock value is 600 per qty and

With total price item1 stock value is  622.2 per qty

Shipping Charges 500,

Item1 Price = 400 x 2 = 800

Item2 Price = 100 x 1 = 100

Total + shipping

900 + 500 = 1400

Comment: what are you thoughts about the problem ?

Comment: Both the ratio's are giving valid results but stock values are different. I am confuse for ratio? base value or total value.